# Need help to install yii2 application advanced template

Tags: php, yii2

I'm new to Yii2, now I'm trying to install yii2 application advanced template.

I did follow these steps:

1 - Download yii2-app-advanced zip file from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

2 - Follow GETTING STARTED guide:

```
 + I'm using Uniform Zero Server (installed in F disk with the path "F:\Server\UniServerZ\www") ok.
 + I creted new folder with name "yii2" in the "www" directory ("F:\Server\UniServerZ\www\yii2")
 + I extracted zip file yii2-app-advanced into "yii2" folder (Every source of yii2-app-advanced now in "yii2" folder so it is the root directory of yii2-app-advanced)
 + Click init.bat file to run "init" and select (0 - Developer mode) and type "yes" to confirm. Done
 + And then I click the yii.bat file, but nothing happened.
 + I tried use this url : localhost/yii2/backend/web/                
   And I get this Error:
   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'F:\Server\UniServerZ\www\yii2\backend\web/../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;F:/Server/UniServerZ/home/us_pear/PEAR') in F:\Server\UniServerZ\www\yii2\backend\web\index.php on line 5
                   or url : localhost/yii2/frontend/web/ 
   And I get this Error too:
   Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'F:\Server\UniServerZ\www\yii2\frontend\web/../../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;F:/Server/UniServerZ/home/us_pear/PEAR') in F:\Server\UniServerZ\www\yii2\frontend\web\index.php on line 5
```

- I checked the "vendor" directory follow this path: 
   F:\Server\UniServerZ\www\yii2\vendor
   But it's empty.

So what should I do to fix this error and install yii2 application advanced template?

(My Uniform Server runs PHP5.4)

Comment: Download file from [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/releases/download/2.0.0-alpha/yii-advanced-app-2.0.0-alpha.tgz)

Comment: While I cannot help you directly I suggest you install [composer](http://getcomposer.org/). It makes the yii2-installation a breeze and is the recommended way.

Comment: Thanks! Hemc, your file is all what I need.

Comment: @user3160078 Composer is the recommended way to work with yii2 and vendor dependencies. I will really suggest you to spend some time and try it. I'm sure you will like Composer and ease of working with it.

Answer (score 9):

**Yii2 Installation Following command:**

**(1) First install Composer (LINUX):**

**Locally:**

*`curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`*

**OR**

**(1) First install Composer (WINDOWS):**

*`C:\Users\username>cd C:\bin`*

*`C:\bin>php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php`*

**Note:** If the above fails due to readfile, use the http url or enable php_openssl.dll in php.ini

*`C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat`*

*`C:\Users\username>composer -V`*

*Composer version 27d8904*

---

**(2) Yii2 framework online downloads:**

**Basic App:**

*`php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.0-beta`*

**Advanced App:**

*`php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-beta`*

---

**(3) Other App Settings Command:**

*`php init`*

*`php yii migrate`*

Comment: thq, "'`php` init" got me there

Answer (score 3):

If you are working on linux, go to the downloaded project and in the terminal type (if you have a composer):

> php composer.phar install

If the composer is not installed go to https://getcomposer.org/download/ After this, yii2 framework and other extensions will be installed at vendor directory. This should fix the problem

Comment: you can do this in windows too (and probably mac)

Answer (score 2):

Install with composer : 
D:\wamp\www> composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced D:\wamp\www\myyii2app

and run php ./init
D:\wamp\www\myyii2app>php ./init

Answer (score 2):

Under Linux, `cd` to the directory of the downloadable project using Terminal and run the following commands:

```
$ php init --env=Development
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 2):

**Installing using Composer**

If you do not have Composer, follow the instructions in the Installing Yii section of the definitive guide to install it.

With Composer installed, you can then install the application using the following commands:

`composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"`

`composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application`

The first command installs the composer asset plugin which allows managing bower and npm package dependencies through Composer. You only need to run this command once for all. The second command installs the advanced application in a directory named yii-application. You can choose a different directory name if you want.

**Install from an Archive File**

Extract the archive file downloaded from [yiiframework.com](http://yiiframework.com) to a directory named advanced that is directly under the Web root.

Then follow the instructions given in the next subsection.

**Preparing application**

After you install the application, you have to conduct the following steps to initialize the installed application. You only need to do these once for all.

1. Execute the init command and select dev as environment.

   `php /path/to/yii-application/init`

   Otherwise, in production execute init in non-interactive mode.

   `php /path/to/yii-application/init --env=Production --overwrite=All`
2. Create a new database and adjust the `components['db']` configuration in `common/config/main-local.php` accordingly.
3. Apply migrations with console command `yii migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

A php component might be missing, i installed mbstring, then restarted the whole process.

```
yum -y install php54w_mbstring
composer init
composer create-project --prefer-dist 
              --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-basic <project-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

****To install YII2-Advance  use these command at your CMD. And see bellow...........****

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10586]
(c) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\admin>e:    (RUN COMMAND)

E:>cd xampp/htdocs    (RUN COMMAND)

E:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced yii-application       (RUN COMMAND)

Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.9)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced (2.0.9)
    Loading from cache

Created project in yii-application
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing yiisoft/yii2-composer (2.0.4)
    Downloading: 100%

- Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.3)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing bower-asset/jquery (2.2.4)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing bower-asset/yii2-pjax (v2.0.6)
  Downloading: 100%`enter code here`
- Installing bower-asset/punycode (v1.3.2)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing bower-asset/jquery.inputmask (3.2.7)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing cebe/markdown (1.1.0)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.8.0)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.9)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer (2.0.5)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-codeception (2.0.5)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing bower-asset/bootstrap (v3.3.7)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap (2.0.6)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-debug (2.0.6)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing bower-asset/typeahead.js (v0.11.1)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing phpspec/php-diff (v1.1.0)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-gii (2.0.5)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.6.0)
  Downloading: 100%
- Installing yiisoft/yii2-faker (2.0.3)
  Downloading: 100%

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files

E:\xampp\htdocs>cd yii-application     (RUN COMMAND)

E:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application>php init      (RUN COMMAND)

Yii Application Initialization Tool v1.0

Which environment do you want the application to be initialized in?

[0] Development
  [1] Production

Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit] 0          (Enter with 0 RUN COMMAND)

Initialize the application under 'Development' environment? [yes|no] yes             (Enter with yes RUN COMMOND)

Start initialization ...

... initialization completed.

E:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application>yii migrate     (RUN COMMOND)

Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.9)

Creating migration history table "migration"...Done.
Total 1 new migration to be applied:
        m130524_201442_init

Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:yes
*** applying m130524_201442_init

> create table {{%user}} ... done (time: 0.225s)
>   *** applied m130524_201442_init (time: 0.310s)

1 migration was applied.

Migrated up successfully.

Finally created yii-application folder in htdocs
E:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application>

Comment: Its very helpful answer to install yii2 at xampp in Window 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Yii2 advanced template go to http://www.yiiframework.com/download/ and download the Yii 2 with advanced application template. Once you have extracted the archive file in the www folder. 
 Then Go to Terminal(For Ubuntu) or cmd(Windows user)

1. For Ubuntu-
   provide root to the extracted folder(advanced) in the Terminal
    cd var/www/html/ashish/advanced
2. Now give the commond- php init
3. Now advance template is installed properly