# Getting Error in installation of yii2 advance template

Tags: installation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm new to Yii2, I'm trying to install yii2 application advanced template.

I did follow these steps:

1 - Download yii2-app-advanced zip file from https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced

**Follow GETTING STARTED guide:**

My vendor directory Show Empty.

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Installing via Composer**
If you do not already have Composer installed, you may do so by following the instructions at getcomposer.org. On Linux and Mac OS X, you'll run the following commands:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

On Windows, you'll download and run Composer-Setup.exe.

Please refer to the Composer Documentation if you encounter any problems or want to learn more about Composer usage.

If you had Composer already installed before, make sure you use an up to date version. You can update Composer by running composer self-update.

With Composer installed, you can install Yii by running the following commands under a Web-accessible folder:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced basic
```

The first command installs the composer asset plugin which allows managing bower and npm package dependencies through Composer. You only need to run this command once for all. The second command installs Yii in a directory named basic. You can choose a different directory name if you want.

```
Note: During the installation Composer may ask for your Github login credentials. This is normal because Composer needs to get enough API rate-limit to retrieve the dependent package information from Github. For more details, please refer to the Composer documentation.

composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced basic
```

Answer (score 1):

Yii2 Installation Following command:

(1) First install Composer (LINUX):

Locally:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

OR

(1) First install Composer (WINDOWS):

```
C:\Users\username>cd C:\bin

C:\bin>php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

**Note:** If the above fails due to readfile, use the http url or enable `php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %>composer.bat*

C:\Users\username>composer -V
```

Composer version 27d8904

(2) Yii2 framework online downloads:

Basic App:

```
php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.0-beta
```

Advanced App:

```
php composer.phar create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced advanced 2.0.0-beta
```

(3) Other App Settings Command:

```
php init

php yii migrate
```

**[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20920347/need-help-to-install-yii2-application-advanced-template)**

Answer (score 0):

> use composer cos you need composer in future too!

and after unzip the advance project in www or htdocs you should navigate to your project with cmd or terminal and type `yii migrate` after that again type `composer update`